# How to find dependencies of php

Tags: installation, php, install-from-source

I need to install LAMP in my home directory. I wish to install from source. It is so difficult to find out dependency of PHP manually, so, is there any easy way to do it. I hope `build-depends` will show all the dependencies, including apache and mysql, also it is related to PHP distribution of ubuntu. Is there any command available to find out all dependencies from source?

Answer (score 2):

There's an APT command `build-dep` which will install all dependencies needed for building standard Ubuntu php packages, e.g.:

```
apt-get build-dep php5
```

If that doesn't work you need to enable sources (`deb-src`) in your APT sources either via a graphical interface or by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

If you need to build all modules you will also need to cherry-pick individual modules from universe (f.e. php5-imap).

Comment: Is there a site where I can check the package dependencies?